# "Tenants" of an argument

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that I thought was "tenants to an argument", but when I search for the definition of "tenant" or "tenants arguments" I get links to landlords and disputes.

**Question**

What is the correct word I'm looking for that describes the units of persuasion that consists of a counterpoint in a persuasive discussion?

**Context**

> Morally, intellectually, and economically, I want people who make less
>   than $250,000 (+/- 100 thousand) to be taxed less than those who make
>   more than $250K. Good for him for being taxed in whatever angle you
>   slice it. Hillary didn't pay enough.
>
> My rationale is based in macro economics and not arbitrary spite,
>   misinformation, or not liking how someone wags their finger. USA is
>   totally f***, due to the distribution of wealth and propaganda
>   through consolidation of media. Democracy is over. Trickle down
>   failed. We're an oligarchy of the rich. For better or worse, I believe
>   Sanders is our last chance at reclaiming one person one vote. All
>   arguments, and persuasions I have start from this **tenant**. If we can't
>   find common ground w/each other on this issue, there is no reason to
>   discuss further.

Comment: You're probably looking for *tenet*

Comment: @Jacinto: You're probably looking for the answer section ;) Oh, you found it. Me confused!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I did find it, eventually. We cannot see it now, but there was an early version of the question that lacked the Context section. That's the one I commented on.

Comment: It doesn't work real great in this case, but note that if you have a word that you're not sure how to spell (or you think you might be finding the wrong word when you try to spell it), you can type a slight misspelling into Google and look at the suggestions it prompts with.  Often it will suggest the word you're looking for.

Comment: *premise* is a better word even if *tenet* is the homonym you were seeking.

Comment: @stevesliva, a premise is a proposition that has a true or false value. "One person one vote" here expresses an "ought". It is a principle, not a proposition. _Tenet_ works well.

Comment: @dangph the declaration about sanders being the last chance is a premise.   This is leading into an argument for a candidate, not for principle.

Comment: @stevesliva, I reread it, and I think you could very well be right. It depends on what the antecedent of "this" is: Sanders being our last chance? Or one person one vote? Or even the fact that we live in an oligarchy? Honestly it's not clear to me what this guy is trying to say there. I think he should forget about fancy technical words for the moment and instead focus on the clarity of his message.

Comment: I can't believe how many well educated Americans I've heard in recent months say "tenant" when they mean "tenet".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are looking for [*tenet* (Oxford Learner’s Dictionary):](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/tenet?q=tenet)

> one of the principles or beliefs that a theory or larger set of beliefs is based on
>
> ● *one of the **basic/central tenets** of Christianity*

Comment: It seems to me, having watched hundreds of YouTube talking-head videos over the last eight years or so, that all Americans, no matter how highly educated they are, pronounce "tenet" with an extra -n- before the final -t. In other words, they pronounce it like "tenant", which is a completely different word. I have never met this mis-pronunciation in the UK.